# NSObject is not storing in NSMutableArray in objective c

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ios5, ios6

I have parsed data stored in an `NSObject` file. I then stored the object file in an array:

```
[array addobject: object];
```

When i print the array, it only contains the first object value.

I declared the array globally, alloced memory for it and allocated memory for the object too.

It is printed like this:

array count 2 and array is:

```
(

    "about 1st orders",

    "about 2nd orders"
)
```

class is `__NSArrayM`

Previously it is correctly storing entire objects.

Any ideas or suggestions to solve this?

Comment: `NSObject` file?  What?

Comment: @Mahesh, you need to write a clearer question. Add more code to your question!

Comment: after 2days i solved my issue, the problem is NSObject has default property "description", i declared description in my own nsobject file, that's why it is not correctly storing in array. Now i renamed that property as descriptionString, now it is working correctly, thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 2):

**Following is describe Logic for You , might be helpful in you case.**

First Create one class  (*name As you want*)

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface MyClassName : NSObject {
    NSString *name; // set as per your requirement.
    NSString *address; // set as per your requirement.
   .
   .
   .
}
@property (retain, readwrite) NSString * name;
@property (retain, readwrite) NSString * address;
.
.
.
```

and Properly `@synthesize` and release reference. (*if Not use `ARC`*)

And add your array in this Class Object And then Get Data such like,

**EDIT:**

```
 NSMutableArray *anOtherArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    for(int i=0; i < listOfArray.count; i++)
    {
         MyClassName *myData = [self.listOfArray objectAtIndex:i];
         NSLog(@"%@", myData.name);
         NSLog(@"%@", myData.address);
         [anOtherArray addObject:myData.name];
         [anOtherArray addObject:myData.address];
    }
```

Comment: if i print NSLog(@"%@", myData.name); i got the value, but my problem is i added that object to another array like [anotherArray addObject:myData]; Then i got only first value. generally another prints like this <MyClassName....> <MyClassName....> <MyClassName....>

Comment: after 2days i solved my issue, the problem is NSObject has default property "description", i declared description in my own nsobject file, that's why it is not correctly storing in array. Now i renamed that property as descriptionString, now it is working correctly, thank you for your answer......

Answer (score 0):

What is the definition of your object that you're storing in the `NSArray`? For custom objects being stored in an array, you should override NSObject's `isEqual` method.

For custom objects being stored in maps such as `NSDictionary`, you'll want to implement `hashcode` too.

Comment: i think he is probably allocating memory inside a loop and thus only one object is getting added. Not sure though cos the question is very ill formed.

Comment: Why `isEqual`? Are you thinking of an NSSet? AFAIk you can store whatever NSObject you want into an NSArray...

Comment: @mrueg NSArray indexOfObject: for example.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what i usually do when putting objects into array :

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface ImageObject : NSObject
{
    NSString *ImageURL;
    NSString *Date;
// put any other stuff here.

}

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *ImageURL;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *Date;
// put any other stuff here too.

@end
```

Then when you want to insert the object :

```
NSMutableArray *yourMutableArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

NSArray *array = [[NSArray alloc]initWithArray:[self.imageDictionary objectForKey:@"images"]];
        for (NSDictionary *dict in array) {
            ImageObject *imgObj = [[ImageObject alloc]init];
            imgObj.ImageURL = [dict objectForKey:@"ImageURL"];
            imgObj.Date = [dict objectForKey:@"LogDate"];
            [yourMutableArray addObject:imgObj];

        }
```

and for calling the items inside the array :

```
ImageObject *imgObj = [[ImageObject alloc]init];

imgObj = [yourMutableArray objectAtIndex:indexOfArray];
```